# Is it true that $F$ is left-adjoint to $U$ in at most one way?

Tags: category-theory

I've heard that if $U : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{S}$ and $F : \mathbf{S} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ are functors between categories, then there's at most one natural isomorphism $$\mathbf{C}(F-,-) \cong \mathbf{S}(-,U-).$$ In other words, $F$ is left-adjoint to $U$ in at most one way.

> **Question.** Is this actually true? If so, how does one prove it? (Please be more specific than "just use the Yoneda Lemma.") If not, what's a counterexample?

Comment: Do you mean "unique up to natural isomorphism", or are you asking if it is *strictly* unique?

Comment: @Hurkyl, natural transformations $F \rightarrow G$ form a set. I want to know if it's correct to say that the set of natural transformations $\mathbf{C}(F-,-) \cong \mathbf{S}(-,U-)$ has at most one element.

Comment: If $U$ and $F$ are the identity functors on the category of $k$-vector spaces, doesn't multiplication by any element of $k^*$ work?

Comment: I guess in that case the isomorphism is natural up to a factor $\lambda\in K^\times$..

Comment: It's definitely not true, any nontrivial natural automorphism of $F, U,  Hom(-, U), Hom(F, -)$ will induce many more natural isomorphisms. One special case is given by stewbasic where $\lambda$ is a natural automorphism of the identity; but there are many more

Comment: So what's wrong with my argument below?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian "adjoints are unique up to a unique isomorphism" that's only true if you fix the unit/counit, not in the absolute. Case in point : for $\lambda \in K^\times$, there is a nonidentity isomorphism $Id \to Id$ whereas they're both adjoints to $Id$ ($Id$ of the category of $K$-vector spaces as before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $U = {\bf C} (X, \_)$, the Yoneda lemma implies that  $\text{Aut}(U) \cong \text{Aut}(X)$.

Of couse very often this kind of functors have a left adjoint $F$.

For each of this automorphisms of the functor we get a *different* functor with the same universal property of $U$ with respect to $F$.

Comment: You mean in the special case where $\mathbf{S} := \mathbf{Set}$, right?

Comment: Yes, of course.